# Passing increased / decreased data from jQuery functions?

Tags: jquery, function

lI have create this jQuery code, that by click on button "Next" it increase number by 8 (8,16,32...) and if you click to button "Previous" it decrease number by 8 (so if you enter Next two times, the number would be 16; than if you press Previous the number would be 8).

I have to pass this thata thru two functions. Problem in my code is that is not passing data? Any idea why?

Here is my code:

```
var clicks = 0; 
$(function(){

    $("#btn2").click(function(){ 
      clicks=clicks+8; 
    });

    $("#btn1").click(function(){ 
        clicks = clicks <= 0 ? clicks : clicks - 8; 
    });

    var test = test2(clicks);

});

var test2 = function(test3){
    return test3;
}

$(function(test3){

    $('#result').html(test3);

});
```

I have also create jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jtw05ff0/1/

Realy thanks for help

Comment: Why on earth would `test3` suddenly be an argument in jQuery's DOM ready handler? `test3` is in fact the `jQuery` object!

Comment: I am a begginer in jQuery, I found an example passing data throu functions, similar in my code

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  He followed all the rules.

Comment: @adeneo You need to be nicer, just because he doesn't know what you do doesn't mean you can be rude.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but there's absolutely no reason whatsoever that `test3` would be anything other than `$`

Comment: Why not just try to help him, vs being a rude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data being passed because you did not have the function executed on click.

See my answer below in the code snip-it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var clicks = 0;

  var test2 = function(data) {
      // Do something
      return data;
    }
  
  // Chain your jQuery calls! :)
  $("#btn2").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    })
    .click(function() {
      clicks = clicks + 8;
      var test = test2(clicks);
      $('#result').html(test);
    });

  $("#btn1").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    })
    .click(function() {
      clicks = clicks <= 0 ? clicks : clicks - 8;
      var test = test2(clicks);
      $('#result').html(test);
    });

  $('#result').html(test2(clicks));

});
```

```css
.btn {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-right: 1px #fff solid;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a class="btn" id="btn1">Previous</a>
</div>
<div><a class="btn" id="btn2">Next</a>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: best, tnx for help :D

Comment: NP :) Don't let some users on this site make you think we are all dicks!

Comment: @Red2078 one question more :) how to create that always start with 0, in your code as you can see, it start with nothing until you press eather Previous or Next, than it start with numbers. So, how to start with 0 without pressing buttons in begining. Tnx

Comment: @krnekires NP :) So just put a value in the <div id='result'>. I edited the answer to show. Since we clear it out and replace with each button click, it is just put in as a placeholder. Did that make sense?

Comment: @Red2078 tnx for answer. Not quite, the thing is, if you have something in var test2 = function(data){} to show, it will show only when you click on each buttons. I whant, in var test2 ... that starts with 0 in the begining of page (by default). Then if you click Next or Previous it updates number.

Comment: Ok, I think I got ya. So I edited my answer. I removed the 0 that was hard coded and instead ran the test2 function at the end of the doc ready. So when doc ready fires, it will execute test2 with the click var.

Comment: you got my point :D realy thanks for answer, I would upvote again, if I could. If you whant I can open new question with this subject (starts with 0)?

Comment: No need to make a new question. I am glad it helped :D